# Why returning a new view doesn't reset form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an appointment class like this:

```
public class Appointment
{
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

In the `HomeController`:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
   return View(new Appointment { Date = DateTime.Now }); //first time to get the form
}
```

and the default `index.cshtml` has a form inside and displays client name and date and when the submit button is pressed, it posts values to `MakeBooking` action method as:

```
public ViewResult MakeBooking(Appointment appt)
{
   return View(); // second time to get the form
}
```

What I don't understand is, I ran the application and filled the form with some value, e,g client name is 'Michael', date is '20/08/2019' and pressed the submit button, and it is directed to `MakeBooking` action method, inside the action method, I returned a view with no data model. so on the second time, the form should have no value since I didn't pass the data model `appt` in the view, but why still I have 'Michael' and '20/08/2019' populated in the view?

This is the `index.cshtml`:

```
@model Appointment

@{ Layout = "_Layout"; }

<form class="m-1 p-1" asp-action="MakeBooking" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ClientName">Your name:</label>
        <input asp-for="ClientName" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Date">Appointment Date:</label>
        <input asp-for="Date" type="text" asp-format="{0:d}" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Make Booking</button>
</form>
```

Comment: please provide your html content

Comment: @NijinKoderi I have added that

Comment: [You're running into this problem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/simonince/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvcs-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value/).  TLDR: use `ModelState.Clear();` on your second action before calling `View()`;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Html Helpers actually check in ModelState for the value to display in a field before they look in the Model.use this in the controller

```
ModelState.Clear();
return View();
```